# When and why to use mind spike

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am unsure of when to use mind spike.

I've noticed that my shadow priest rotation often boils down to the following:

> shadow word: pain
>
> vampiric touch
>
> mind blast
>
> devouring plague
>
> vampiric embrace
>
> mindbender
>
> shadow word: death

I'm not sure where mind spike should fit, I do know that it cancels all damage over time abilities so I can't think of when to use it.

Also, is there anything I can do to improve my rotation.

Is there any difference in the approach I should take for solo, raid and dungeon play?

Comment: Should it be just before the DOTs (damage over time) expire?

Comment: I often begin with vampiric touch for one on one fights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind Spike is primarily for enemies which will die soon so that dots will not tick longer.

Here is a [shadow priest guide](http://wod.wowhead.com/guide=2163) for the actual game version with more informations. The best rotation depends a lot of factors like enemies, buffs, talents and glyphs. Some Examples:

- The Talent [Surge of Darkness](http://wod.wowhead.com/spell=162448) lets you cast Mind Spike withour removing dots from the target when it procs. This means you should cast it always when the talent procs.
- The Talent [Clarity of Power](http://wod.wowhead.com/spell=155246) lets you play with a rotation without dots.
- [Glyph of Mind Spike](http://wod.wowhead.com/item=45758) makes your Mind Blast casts instant after casting two Mind Spikes. This is useful if you're using Mind Spike on lots of low health adds.

Comment: Yeah, when Mind Spike was originally introduced to the game (WotLK?), it was billed as a spell for quick kills.  Like when you're out questing and don't want to dot up enemies and wait forever for them to die.